# Login.php code not retrieving email during login process

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication, phpmyadmin

I'm using an online video example of a login/logout/member page, trying to implement it for my website.  I have a live server from justhost, I created a db and put in some dummy user information into my users table.  I created a connect.php file which does just that, and I ecchoed out a success message if it will connect to my database and it worked.  When I try to login to display a link to the member page, I continuously get an error message saying the email I entered is not found, but the email is in the database table.  What am I doing wrong?  here's the login.php file, sorry for the length of it.

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Member System - Login</title>
</head>
<body>

    <?php

        $form = "<form action='./login.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='user'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='password'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type='submit' name='loginbtn' value='Login' /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>";

    if($_POST['loginbtn']){
        $email = $_POST['user'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if ($email){
            if ($password){
                require("connect.php");

                $password = md5(md5("sdf5jkl".$password."jfdkSDf4"));

                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
                $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if($numrows == 1){
                    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
                    $dbid = $row['id'];
                    $dbpass = $row['password'];
                    $dbemail = $row['email'];
                    $dbactive = $row['active'];

                    if($password == $dbpass){
                        if($dbactive == 1){
                            //set session info
                            $_SESSION['id'] = $dbid;
                            $_SESSION['email'] = $dbemail;

                            echo "You have been logged in as <b>$dbemail</b>.  <a href='./member.php'>Click here</a> to go to the member page.";

                        }
                        else
                            echo "You must activate your account to login. $form";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "You did not enter the correct password. $form";
                }
                else
                    echo "The email you entered was not found. $form";

                mysql_close();
            }
            else
                echo "You must enter your password. $form";
        }
        else
            echo "You must enter your email. $form";
    }
    else
        echo $form;

    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your tricky password md5 generation and protect $email parameter from sql injection ;)

Comment: Try print_r $_POST and see what it outputs.

Comment: Try to echo your $query you'll see if there is something wrong with it. Also, note that your script is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I thought that encryption could be a problem.  I just tested the encryption.  I set the password originally to "password", then I displayed the encrypted password on the screen and changed it to the encrypted in the database.  But the password isn't the problem...problem is it's not finding my $email from the database...

Comment: We know the password isn't the issue because the message you're getting comes from the `if($numrows == 1)` which is coming from the query. As mentioned above, do a `print_r($_POST);` and see if there's any values.

Comment: I'm no expert in php so if you have advice, just learning so please if you can, give me detailed explanation.  Where would I insert echo $query;? Right after I set it?  Or where would I put the print statement?

Comment: Right after `require("connect.php");` put `echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";`.

Comment: Debugging tips. Having spaces around the $email's value could cause you headaches so try trimming it with trim(). Also if there is a duplicate email in the Db then the if($numrows == 1) condition will fail. Last as suggested print_r the $_POST array to see what is in there. Or execute the sql inside your phpmyadmin to see if a result is actually returned.

Comment: @Sean I tried that, with the rest of the code.  All it did was display the email which I put in the email textbox. it said echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='my email which I put in the textbox'";  Is that what it was supposed to do?  I also did a print_r($_POST) and it just displayed everything that I put in the text boxes...

Comment: If you use phpMyAdmin (or another SQL Interface) can you try pasting the query directly into there? What results do you get? How many rows are there?

Comment: @Chris like I said earlier, I'm new at this.  I know I have 14 rows in my table.  What would you like it to show you?  Tell me exactly what to type in the phpmyadmin SQL query line

Comment: Out of your 14 rows, do any records have the exact same email?

Answer (score 1):

About halfway down your code, you have these lines:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Let's change it temporarily to this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";
echo '<pre>'. $sql .'</pre>';
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo '<pre>'. $numrows .'</pre>';
```

When you try to log in now, you'll probably see something like this at the top of your page:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='thenamethatijusttypedin'
2
```

If the number is equal to 1, then your code *should* work as you wrote it. If the number is something else, then you can learn more by copying the SQL query above it, then running it in your database platform (i.e.: phpMyAdmin).

As others have mentioned previously, you should clean up your input. You can remove leading and trailing whitespace with the `trim($email);` command.

Once you feel a bit more confident with coding, you should look into a database query tool called [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Right now, your query is vulnerable to something called SQL Injection. If I were to put an apostrophe in the `user` field, then the query would break. Hackers can use this to break into your website. PDO protects against this and makes writing queries a bit easier.

Comment: I found another example that I think uses PDO...even though I don't know exactly what it is.  I changed my code to the one you provided and on the top it gave me the reply with a 1...so as you say, it should work but it doesn't.  I don't know what's wrong.  As I wrote to Sean above, I'll just try to look for a better login/logout/memberpage tutorial examples and hopefully those will work.  Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your code in terms of not managing to find the user. Here are a few things to try.

```
$email = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Should be:

```
$email = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user']));
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
```

`trim()` will remove any extra spaces that could be messing up the query and `mysql_real_escape_string()` escapes special characters.

If you are getting the the data correctly by checking `print_r($_POST)` and the query looks fine by running `echo "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'";` or running `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='your_email'` in phpmyadmin, then maybe you have duplicate emails in your user table? If you do, you shouldn't. Try removing the duplicate. You should also check the password at the same time you're checking the email. Here's an example:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'");`

Comment: Tried it, no luck.  In phpmyadmin, I typed in my email in the end and it showed all the rows with my information, so it found me as a user.  I don't know what's wrong.  Maybe I'll just keep searching online to find better examples.  As everyone says, this sample I found isn't very safe anyway, maybe another example will work.  Thanks for your advice, Sean

Comment: Like I said, nothing seems wrong with the code. Has to be something small. Maybe try limiting it to 1 record to make sure you're only getting one record. `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1");`

Comment: I only have the one "user" inserted in the table, my data, just to test it out.  Could it be something with mysql on my server?  I'm using justhost.com...maybe it's something with my domain name folder inside public_html?

Comment: But if you can connect to the database then I don't see the issue.

Comment: True.  Oh well, on to the next one.  I might be coming back to ask you some more questions later if you don't mind :)

Comment: It's frustrating because it's close. It makes no sense as to why it doesn't find the user. Anyways, ask away! Don't mind at all.

Comment: Hey Sean, need some help again...do you think you can look over my code files if I send them to your email?  There are 4 or 5 of them and I wouldn't be able to post them on here